# Execute a script before login screen

Tags: shell-script, login, startup, xrandr

I am trying to run a script before the login screen in `Ubuntu 19.04`. The script checks if there is an external monitor connected to my notebook and if there is one it changes the resolution to 3440x1440@44 and switches off the internal laptop display. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

EXTERNAL_OUTPUT="HDMI-1-1"
INTERNAL_OUTPUT="eDP-1-1"

xrandr |grep $EXTERNAL_OUTPUT | grep " connected "
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    xrandr --output $INTERNAL_OUTPUT --off
    xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_44.00"  299.75  3440 3664 4024 4608  1440 1443 1453 1479 -hsync +vsync
    xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 "3440x1440_44.00"
    xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode "3440x1440_44.00"
else
    xrandr --output $INTERNAL_OUTPUT --auto --output $EXTERNAL_OUTPUT --off
fi
```

I have tried to put this script both in `~/.profile` and also in the Startup Applications but my GDM login is still present only on my notebook screen. I want this script to be executed even before that time so that I am not present with a black picture upon starting my computer.

[UPDATE]: I have tried both proposed solutions but they were both not working. First I have tried the solution of Fiximan. I have created the monitor-check.service in `/etc/systemd/system` and tried to execute the `/bin/bash /home/user/monitor-check.service` and it successfully changed the laptop resolution to 3440x1440. Then I have tried to execute: `sudo systemctl start monitor-check.sh` and this is the status message:

```
monitor-check.service - Service to check for external monitors during boot.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/monitor-check.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-07-09 19:27:17 CEST; 5s ago
  Process: 4177 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/Documents/scripts/display_setup.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4177 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 09 19:27:17 acer systemd[1]: Started Service to check for external monitors during boot..
Jul 09 19:27:17 acer bash[4177]: Can't open display
Jul 09 19:27:17 acer bash[4177]: Can't open display
Jul 09 19:27:17 acer systemd[1]: monitor-check.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 09 19:27:17 acer systemd[1]: monitor-check.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have tried to add the environment variable to the Xauthority by adding:
`Environment=XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority` to the `Service` section but it didn't help.

I have also tried the proposed solution by Praveen but it didn't work either. In fact, I have added my script to `/etc/profile.d` directory but it didn't execute the script so my resolution was still the old one.

In conclusion, the only two solutions which worked was to add the script to the `~/.profile` or to add it manually to the Startup Applications but both solutions change the resolution and switches off the internal laptop display after logon to the system.

Comment: Best practice is to answer your own question and mark it as solved even if you found a solution on your own. That way others who have the same problem will directly know that an answer exists. Thanks for the feedback on my question.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't find a solution. Unfortunately, both proposed methods didn't work out for my scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 19.04 uses `systemd` so the preferred way for such scripts would be using a sysd-service.

For this you will need two files: 1) the `script.sh` you already wrote (I assume it is tested and functional) and 2) a unit file defining the systemd service.

An example of the latter would be:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service to check for external monitors during boot.

[Service]
Type=Simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /path/to/your/monitor/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`Description` and `ExecStart` should be self-explanatory, `Type=Simple` means the script is to be run once only (and not every X seconds or so) and `WantedBy=multi-user.target` makes it run once you have a "normal" boot (not shutdown, not rescue mode, and graphics optional). Of course you can make the script executable and not add `/bin/bash` in the `ExecStart`-line.

The script goes to `/etc/systemd/system` e.g. by the name `monitor-check.service`, note that the `.service`-suffix is mandatory! Set ownership to `root` and permissions to `644`.

You can test the service by

```
systemctl start monitor-check
```

or

```
service monitor-check start
```

and check the status by replacing `start` with `status` in the above commands.

To enable is as boot service use:

```
systemctl enable monitor-check.service
```

If you now look at `service monitor-check status`, you should read `enabled` in the `Loaded:`-line.

Of course the script itself should be owned by root and have `644`-permissions for safety reasons. Best is to keep it in new directories like e.g. `/etc/my_scripts` or `/etc/systemd/my_scripts`.

After reboot you can use the status of the service to check for its exit code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the proposed solution doesn't work for displays. You can check the update I have posted in my original post for additional information why.

Comment: @GeorgеStoyanov I assume the execution is set to the wrong timing then. Unfortunately, I have no monitor to test it myself but `graphical.target` instead of `multi-user.target` might do the trick as it waits for the graphics server to start. If you're up for some testing, hopefully.

Comment: Just in case, after the script created with proper permissions, execute `systemctl daemon-reload` to tell about the changes also.

Answer (score 2):

```
Kindly add the script in /etc/profile.d
```

If You want it to be user specific Kindly add in below location so it will execute when user logins

```
/home/username/.profile
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, first of all, why kindly? And second of all, I want this evaluation to be executed before the login screen. So according to my understanding, if I have a couple of users, then the `/home/username/.profile` will be executed only after the particular user logs into the system, but not before. This is exactly what I get now. I will test the `/etc/profile.d` in the evening when I am back home.

Comment: your solution didn't work. I have added an `[Update]` to my original thread with a summary of the additional tests I have done.